# how to get keycloak inject cookie with auth server running on docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, keycloak, openid-connect

Apologies for my very wordy post. I'm using keycloak, openid connect, nginx, docker and react in my application.

keycloak is running on docker with for example ( http://auth-server.com/auth)

When I bring up my frontend on localhost:3000. It redirected me to the log-in page with ( http://auth-server.com/auth/login.html ), then after the log in, I need to get current logged-in user from my back-end micro service which requires cookie with session and X-AUTH-USER injected by keycloak. I believe because frontend is running on localhost, and keycloak is on a different domain. cookie and the http header is not being injected with the subsequent requests.

How can I get keycloak to inject the cookie for every single subsequent request?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how OpenID Connect is supposed to be used. OpenID Connect is a protocol for **federated authentication**. Websites can not set cookies for other websites - that would be a security issue.

OpenID Connect is designed for being [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) without the use of *cookies* and *sessions*. With OpenID Connect you are using a self-contained [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) *access token* sendt in the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` HTTP Header.

With this design, it is much easier to create **stateless backends** that you easily can deploy on e.g. modern [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) platforms and scale elastically or do rolling deployments without downtime.

If you still want to use *cookies* and *sessions* you can have a service that creates those session on **redirect** from the OpenID authentication when you have got the *access token*.

Comment: I do have the token and current logged-in user from keycloak. re-writing all backend services is not an option. There has to be a way to get authentication process working on local machine with keycloak right?.

Comment: @user4900074 yes, you can register a client with redirect_uri to localhost with keycloak to authenticate on local machine

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.
my keycloak.json looks like this

```
  "realm": "example",
  "auth-server-url": "http://auth-server.com/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "my-react-client",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```